# redirect files in a folder but not the folder using .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to use a regex and htaccess to redirect all files in a folder to another folder, but not the actual folder itself.

So example.com/folder/file1.html redirects to example.com/2ndfolder/file1.html

but example.com/folder/ and example.com/folder do not redirect.

I understand how to redirect everything, but not redirecting if there is not a file referenced has be stock

Comment: Seeing your broken code would help.

Comment: @user2332834 thanks for confirming! Happy to hear this is what you were looking for. If this solved your problem, can you please "accept" the answer by selecting the check mark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have it working for ALL content, but just need to redirect files only, then you can add a RewriteCond to make sure the request is for a legitimate file. For example (assuming this is going in the .htaccess under /folder/)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /2ndfolder/$1 [L]
```

Or if you wanting an external redirect:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/2ndfolder/$1 [L]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed - only if there is a filename then redirect.  Thx!

Comment: @user2332834 thanks for confirming! Happy to hear this is what you were looking for. If this solved your problem, can you please "accept" the answer by selecting the check mark next to it. Thank you!